# Block Behavior, but for Function Assignment instead of Variable Assignment

Tags: programming, replacement, expression-manipulation, scoping, assignment

We can define a function using a variable `b` that does not appear as an argument, and then using `Block`, change the output of the function by modifying `b`. For example, consider the below where `b` does not appear as an argument to `g`.

```
g[a_, x_] := a + x + b

g[1, x]
(* output is 1 + b + x *)

Block[{b = E}, g[1, x]]
(* output is 1 + E + x *)
```

What I am looking for is essentially the same thing but where `b` is instead a function `f[x]` and I can modify `f[x]` without it appearing as an argument to `g`. What I want is apparent in the following.

```
g[a_, x_] := a + x + f[x]

Block[{f[x] = x^2}, g[1, x]]
(* where output would be 1 + x^2 + x *)
```

Of course, an error appears because `Block` can't assign a value to a function.

*How I get the behavior I want in a decent, safe, and not-so-convoluted way?*

### Conditions

First, I do not want to have to change the definition of `g` in any way.

Second, I have considered syntactic replacement with `/.` but this is not mathematically safe and I am looking for something mathematically safe. For example,

`(f[x] + D[f[x], x]) /. f[x] -> x^2`

outputs

`` x^2 + f`[x] ``.

What I am looking for would have the output

`x^2 + 2x`.

`Block`, with variable assignment, has the nice behavior. For example, compare the following.

```
D[y, x] /. y -> x
(* outputs 0 *)

Block[{y = x}, D[y, x]]
(* outputs 1 *)
```

Comment: Does `Block[{f=Function[{x}, x^2]}, g[1, x]]` solve your problem?

Comment: or `Block[{f}, f[x_] := x^2; g[1, x]]`

Comment: @rhermans Both seem to work. If they do not after a deeper look, I will update. Thank you both.